# Inspecting the value of a JS variable in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This is fragment of a JS plugin that I'm using on my site. I'd like to inspect the value of `isTouchDevice` directly in the console. Just typing `isTouchDevice` reurns an 'undefined' error.

```
(function($) {

    "use strict";

    $.maxmegamenu = function(menu, options) {

        var plugin = this;

        var $menu = $(menu);

        plugin.settings = {};

        var isTouchDevice = function() {
            return ('ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0);
        };
})(jQuery);
```

How I can inspect the value of `isTouchDevice` variable in Chrome console?

**Edit 1:**

To clarify, First, I need to be able to inspect the value of `var isTouchDevice` directly in the console, without adding any code. Second, `console.log(isTouchDevice)` would return an 'undefined error' probably due to the variable encapsulation (it's not available in the global scope) so just console-logging it is not a way to go.

Comment: For simplicity, you can just run `('ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0)` in the chrome console. Otherwise you can put a breakpoint after declaration and add a watch in your dev tools

Comment: note that isTouchDevice in your code snippet is assigned with a function. to get the value you need to access it by invoking it console.log(isTouchDevice());  you also need to call it in the right scope which is  inside the block var isTouchDevice is declared

Comment: @RGraham, this is a great recommendation which solves my problem - executing the expression directly in the console..

Comment: @lid Just out of curiousity as my probelm has already been solved. Due to scoping, I will not be able to inspect `isTouchDevice()` directly in the console?

Comment: @luqo33, that is right, to have access to the method you need to be in the right scope chain.  see: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/db528b893d477b49775a  hypothetically if you need to run arbitrary code within a particular scope/conext in console, the approach eck mentioned is the way to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also add a `debugger;` statement at the end of your maxmegamenu function.

When chrome breaks on that statement the console will be within the context of that function and `isTouchDevice` should be defined then.

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log(isTouchDevice);`

or other `console` methods like
`.info` `.warn` `.error` `.debug`

or you can use grouping with `console.group('this is some event');` then close group with `console.groupEnd();`

last method is `console.groupCollapsed('some title of group');`, what will create group, but will be collapsed in console, consuming less space